# I was working on a small project and I came across this problem in GUI JAVA Swing. I have separated out the main error lines for easy access

Tags: java, swing

I was working on my GUI project and i wanted to add an animated GIF but the code wasn't running then i decided to google the answer (Obvious response) but i failed then i looked into some stack overflow codes and found the second code from here but it also failed as well. Please someone help me escape this misery.

I Used this code first and it gave me this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
        at Class_GUI.<init>(Class_GUI.java:54)
        at Class_Driver.main(Class_Driver.java:3)
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

> The Code:

```
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class Class_GUI implements MouseListener {
        private JFrame jFrame = new JFrame ();
        private JPanel jPanel = new JPanel ();
    
        private JLabel minusLabel = new JLabel ("-");
        private JLabel closeLabel = new JLabel ("X");
        private JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel ();
    
        public Class_GUI () {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("E:\\Mehroz\\The Dollars\\The_Dollars\\Icons & Images\\Dollars_Logo.png");
    
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation (WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.setSize (700, 900);
            jFrame.setUndecorated (true);
            jFrame.setShape (new RoundRectangle2D.Double (0, 0, 700, 900, 25, 25));
            jFrame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
            jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
            jFrame.setLayout (null);
            FrameDragListener frameDragListener = new FrameDragListener (jFrame);
            jFrame.addMouseListener (frameDragListener);
            jFrame.addMouseMotionListener (frameDragListener);
    
            jPanel.setBounds (0, 0, 700, 900);
            jPanel.setBackground (new Color (0, 0, 0, 150));
            jPanel.setLayout (null);
    
            minusLabel.setBounds (645, 5, 25, 30);
            minusLabel.setForeground (new Color (0, 0, 0));
            minusLabel.setFont (new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
            minusLabel.setToolTipText ("Minimize");
            minusLabel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createBevelBorder (0));
            minusLabel.setCursor (Cursor.getPredefinedCursor (Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            minusLabel.addMouseListener (this);
    
            closeLabel.setBounds (670, 5, 25, 30);
            closeLabel.setForeground (new Color (255, 0, 0));
            closeLabel.setFont (new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
            closeLabel.setToolTipText ("Close");
            closeLabel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createBevelBorder (0));
            closeLabel.setCursor (Cursor.getPredefinedCursor (Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            closeLabel.addMouseListener (this);
```

> Error Line

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage (Transparency.OPAQUE,
Image.SCALE_SMOOTH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(jFrame.getClass().getResource("DollarsLogo.gif"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

```
            ImageIcon icons = new ImageIcon(img);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icons);
            jPanel.add(label);
    
            jPanel.add (minusLabel);
            jPanel.add (closeLabel);
            jFrame.add (jPanel);
            jFrame.setVisible (true);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource () == minusLabel) {
                jFrame.setState (JFrame.ICONIFIED);
            } else if (e.getSource () == closeLabel) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) { }
    
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e) { }
    
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource () == minusLabel) {
                minusLabel.setBackground (new Color (110, 225, 110, 150));
            } else if (e.getSource () == closeLabel) {
                closeLabel.setBackground (new Color (110, 225, 110, 150));
            }
            jFrame.repaint ();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource () == minusLabel) {
                minusLabel.setBackground (new Color (255, 255, 255, 225));
            } else if (e.getSource () == closeLabel) {
                closeLabel.setBackground (new Color (255, 255, 255, 225));
            }
            jFrame.repaint ();
        }
    }
    /**<\>------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</>**/
```

> Then I Tried this code from some of the previous answers and it game me a null pointer exception error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at PlayAnimatedGif$AnimatedGif.<init>(PlayAnimatedGif.java:135)
        at PlayAnimatedGif$TestPane.<init>(PlayAnimatedGif.java:62)
        at PlayAnimatedGif$1.run(PlayAnimatedGif.java:47) <14 internal calls>
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

> The Code:

```
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
    import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
    import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;
    import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
    import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    
    public class PlayAnimatedGif {
    
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            new PlayAnimatedGif ();
        }
    
        public PlayAnimatedGif () {
            EventQueue.invokeLater (new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel (UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName ());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }
    
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
                    frame.add (new TestPane ());
                    frame.pack ();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
                    frame.setVisible (true);
                }
            });
        }
    
        public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    
            private AnimatedGif ag;
    
            public TestPane () {
                URL url = getClass ().getResource ("DollarsLogo.gif");
                try {
                    ag = new AnimatedGif (this, url);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace ();
                }
                ag.play ();
            }
    
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
                return new Dimension (200, 200);
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent (g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create ();
                BufferedImage currentFrame = ag.getCurrentFrame ();
                if (currentFrame != null) {
                    int x = (getWidth () - currentFrame.getWidth ()) / 2;
                    int y = (getHeight () - currentFrame.getHeight ()) / 2;
                    g2d.drawImage (currentFrame, x, y, this);
                }
                g2d.dispose ();
            }
        }
    
        public static class AnimatedGif {
    
            public enum DisposalMethod {
                RESTORE_TO_BACKGROUND,
                RESTORE_TO_PREVIOUS,
                DO_NOT_DISPOSE,
                UNSPECIFIED;
    
                public static DisposalMethod find (String text) {
    
                    DisposalMethod dm = UNSPECIFIED;
    
                    switch (text) {
                        case "restoreToBackgroundColor":
                            dm = RESTORE_TO_BACKGROUND;
                            break;
                    }
    
                    return dm;
    
                }
            }
    
            private List<ImageFrame> frames;
            private int frame;
            private Timer playTimer;
    
            private JComponent player;
    
            protected AnimatedGif (JComponent value) {
                this.player = value;
                frames = new ArrayList<> (25);
                playTimer = new Timer (0, new ActionListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                        frame++;
                        if (frame >= frames.size ()) {
                            frame = 0;
                        }
                        player.repaint ();
                        playTimer.setDelay (frames.get (0).getGraphicControlExtension ().getDelayTime ());
                    }
                });
            }
    
            public AnimatedGif (JComponent player, URL url) throws IOException {
                this (player);
```

> The Error Line

```
try (InputStream is = url.openStream (); ImageInputStream stream = 
     ImageIO.createImageInputStream (is))
```

```
    {
                    Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders (stream);
                    if (!readers.hasNext ()) {
                        throw new RuntimeException ("no image reader found");
                    }
                    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next ();
                    reader.setInput (stream);            // don't omit this line!
                    int n = reader.getNumImages (true);  // don't use false!
                    System.out.println ("numImages = " + n);
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        BufferedImage image = reader.read (i);
                        ImageFrame imageFrame = new ImageFrame (image);
    
                        IIOMetadata imd = reader.getImageMetadata (i);
                        Node tree = imd.getAsTree ("javax_imageio_gif_image_1.0");
                        NodeList children = tree.getChildNodes ();
    
                        for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength (); j++) {
                            Node nodeItem = children.item (j);
                            NamedNodeMap attr = nodeItem.getAttributes ();
                            switch (nodeItem.getNodeName ()) {
                                case "ImageDescriptor":
                                    ImageDescriptor id = new ImageDescriptor (
                                            getIntValue (attr.getNamedItem ("imageLeftPosition")),
                                            getIntValue (attr.getNamedItem ("imageTopPosition")),
                                            getIntValue (attr.getNamedItem ("imageWidth")),
                                            getIntValue (attr.getNamedItem ("imageHeight")),
                                            getBooleanValue (attr.getNamedItem ("interlaceFlag")));
                                    imageFrame.setImageDescriptor (id);
                                    break;
                                case "GraphicControlExtension":
                                    GraphicControlExtension gc = new GraphicControlExtension (
                                            DisposalMethod.find (getNodeValue (attr.getNamedItem ("disposalMethod"))),
                                            getBooleanValue (attr.getNamedItem ("userInputFlag")),
                                            getBooleanValue (attr.getNamedItem ("transparentColorFlag")),
                                            getIntValue (attr.getNamedItem ("delayTime")) * 10,
                                            getIntValue (attr.getNamedItem ("transparentColorIndex")));
                                    imageFrame.setGraphicControlExtension (gc);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        frames.add (imageFrame);
                    }
                } finally {
                }
            }
    
            public BufferedImage getCurrentFrame () {
                // If this was a optimised GIF, we would need to be
                // merging frames together to produce the current frame
                // This would then need to be reset each time we cycle...
                return frames.isEmpty () ? null : frames.get (frame).getImage ();
            }
    
            public void play () {
                if (!frames.isEmpty ()) {
                    frame = 0;
                    playTimer.setDelay (frames.get (0).getGraphicControlExtension ().getDelayTime ());
                    playTimer.start ();
                    player.repaint ();
                }
            }
    
            public void stop () {
                playTimer.stop ();
            }
    
            protected String getNodeValue (Node node) {
                return node == null ? null : node.getNodeValue ();
            }
    
            protected int getIntValue (Node node) {
                return node == null ? 0 : getIntValue (node.getNodeValue ());
            }
    
            protected boolean getBooleanValue (Node node) {
                return node == null ? false : getBooleanValue (node.getNodeValue ());
            }
    
            protected int getIntValue (String value) {
                return value == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt (value);
            }
    
            protected boolean getBooleanValue (String value) {
                return value == null ? false : Boolean.parseBoolean (value);
            }
    
            public class ImageFrame {
    
                private BufferedImage image;
                private ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor;
                private GraphicControlExtension graphicControlExtension;
    
                public ImageFrame (BufferedImage image) {
                    this.image = image;
                }
    
                protected void setImageDescriptor (ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor) {
                    this.imageDescriptor = imageDescriptor;
                }
    
                protected void setGraphicControlExtension (GraphicControlExtension graphicControlExtension) {
                    this.graphicControlExtension = graphicControlExtension;
                }
    
                public GraphicControlExtension getGraphicControlExtension () {
                    return graphicControlExtension;
                }
    
                public BufferedImage getImage () {
                    return image;
                }
    
                public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor () {
                    return imageDescriptor;
                }
    
            }
    
            public class GraphicControlExtension {
    
                private DisposalMethod disposalMethod;
                private boolean userInputFlag;
                private boolean transparentColorFlag;
                private int delayTime;
                private int transparentColorIndex;
    
                public GraphicControlExtension (DisposalMethod disposalMethod, boolean userInputFlag, boolean transparentColorFlag, int delayTime, int transparentColorIndex) {
                    this.disposalMethod = disposalMethod;
                    this.userInputFlag = userInputFlag;
                    this.transparentColorFlag = transparentColorFlag;
                    this.delayTime = delayTime;
                    this.transparentColorIndex = transparentColorIndex;
                }
    
                public int getDelayTime () {
                    return delayTime;
                }
    
                public DisposalMethod getDisposalMethod () {
                    return disposalMethod;
                }
    
                public int getTransparentColorIndex () {
                    return transparentColorIndex;
                }
    
                public boolean isTransparentColorFlag () {
                    return transparentColorFlag;
                }
    
                public boolean isUserInputFlag () {
                    return userInputFlag;
                }
    
            }
    
            public class ImageDescriptor {
    
                private int imageLeftPosition;
                private int imageTopPosition;
                private int imageHeight;
                private int imageWeight;
                private boolean interlaced;
    
                public ImageDescriptor (int imageLeftPosition, int imageTopPosition, int imageHeight, int imageWeight, boolean interlaced) {
                    this.imageLeftPosition = imageLeftPosition;
                    this.imageTopPosition = imageTopPosition;
                    this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
                    this.imageWeight = imageWeight;
                    this.interlaced = interlaced;
                }
    
                public int getImageHeight () {
                    return imageHeight;
                }
    
                public int getImageLeftPosition () {
                    return imageLeftPosition;
                }
    
                public int getImageTopPosition () {
                    return imageTopPosition;
                }
    
                public int getImageWeight () {
                    return imageWeight;
                }
    
                public boolean isInterlaced () {
                    return interlaced;
                }
    
            }
    
        }
    
    }
```

Sorry for this monstrosity.

I Hope the COVID kills all the bugs in my codes.

p.s. Don't ask why the Gif name is The Dollars. ;)

Comment: *"Sorry for this monstrosity."* No worries! I'll just ignore it till there is a [mre].

Comment: *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:* isn't that a clue??? *BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage (Transparency.OPAQUE,
Image.SCALE_SMOOTH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);* - if that is the statement causing the problem then start by reading the API for the proper parameters to be used in the constructor.

Comment: The "basic" problem, as I'm now reading it stems from `img = ImageIO.read(jFrame.getClass().getResource("DollarsLogo.gif"));` - basically `jFrame.getClass().getResource("DollarsLogo.gif")` is returning `null`, meaning it can't find the named resource

Comment: Hint: never use  null LayoutManager until you are an expert in swing. And experts usually write their own in the few cases where the normal layout managers aren't enough (extremely rare cases, mind you).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies i have found the error and fixed it.